# Launching Programs (example: Vim) from Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Using the `Turtle` shell scripting library I am trying to launch a program, i.e:

```
shell "vim" empty
```

The problem is that this yields the warning `Warning: Input is not from a terminal` and causes Vim to lag for a few seconds before finally launching.

**Questions:**

1. Is `shell` the best Turtle function to launch an external program from haskell?
2. If so, is there any way to get around errors like the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use functions from the [process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) library, specifically [createProcess](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess) or [runProcess](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:runProcess).

Relevant turtle thread on the issue [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/issues/29).

[Example usage](https://github.com/purescript/psc-package/blob/e57afd280fa46ff8ee8a4edcb6491db8a5668e0d/app/Main.hs#L268-L275).

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually setting up I/O to the vty. E.g. in bash: `vim < $TTY > $TTY`. I guess turtle is doing that with its own file descriptors under the hood, based on the warning, so you should be able to manually set up those redirects (or just use the command I gave via `shell`). You just need to make sure you've got a `TTY` environment var around.

Comment: I get "ambiguous redirect" when trying this out.

Comment: Tells me the `TTY` environment variable isn't set.  You can find it with the `tty` command.  Anyway, seems like you found your answer already.